# Return the "valid" numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers

I need to write a function in python, which returns the valid measurements for a list of numbers. A measure is invalid, if the closest other measurement is less that 0.1 second away. Also, the output list should be the same length as the length of the input list.

Thus:

`[5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5]` should return `[True, True, True, False, False, False, True]`

I have approached the problem in the following fashion:

```
list = [5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5]
newlist = []

for i, j in zip(list, list[1:]):
    if j - i >= .1:
        newlist.append(True)
    else:
        newlist.append(False)
```

The problem is that this returns the following list:
`[True, True, True, False, False, True]` with one `False` measurement missing.

How can I write this code differently?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The statement of your problem implies that the length of the output list should be smaller than the length of the input list by 1. However, the example that follows shows that they are equal, while the actual output that you're getting appears to be correct. Please consider rephrasing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. There's only 2 false measurements. The one at 10.37 and the one at 10.45. The measurement at `10.34` is OK since it happens several seconds after the previous one.

Your result has 1 less value than the input list because you're comparing values 2 by 2.

It's a typical "intervals & values" problem. There's one less interval than values.

Write your test like this for better performance (list comprehension):

```
measures = [5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5]
print([abs(measures[i+1]-measures[i])>0.1 for i in range(len(measures)-1)])

[True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

(your code creates a lot of useless temporary lists. Also avoid using `list` as a variable)

However, if you want to invalidate *all* measurements which are too close, no fancy stuff, with sliding window:

```
measures = [5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5]
result = [True] * len(measures)

for i in range(len(measures)-1):
    validity = abs(measures[i+1]-measures[i])>0.1
    if result[i]:  # don't overwrite an already invalidated value
        result[i] = validity
    result[i+1] = validity

print(result)

[True, True, True, False, False, False, True]
```

Details:

- creates a `result` array of the size of the input array (`*` operator, nice)
- iterates through all elements of the list but the last one
- compares current value and the "next" value to compute a `validity` flag (`True` or `False`)
- if current `result` is already `False`, it means that previous iteration already invalidated it, leave as-is, else set to `validity`
- set "next" result to `validity` (`i+1` index)

No temporary list creation, should be fast enough.

Comment: The OP's requirement "the closest other measurement is less tha[n] 0.1 second away" seems to go both directions: since `10.34` and `10.45` are less than 0.1 second away from each other, *both* of them are invalid, hence the OP's stated output is correct. Do you dispute my interpretation of the OP? You may want to give another answer that corresponds to my interpretation, since your answer is quite good otherwise.

Comment: This is a homework for my programming class and it says that there should be 3 "False" measurements. While it is true, that the measurement at 10.34 happens several seconds after the previous one, it appears less than 0.1 sec before the next one and is therefore, also False.

Comment: okay, I have added another version which creates 3 `False` values. No list comprehension (sob :)) but simple.

Comment: Can you explain what the code actually does? :) I am very curious to learn what you did.

Comment: Genius! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this way, 1st insert dummy valid value into head and tail of list so that later on we can compare against before and after value.
Then start perform checking on the value not included the dummy we added.

```
# rename var name to lst, not recommended to use keyword list as var name
lst = [5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5]
lst2 = [lst[0]+1] + lst + [lst[-1]+1]
# use absolute function so we checking the absolute difference
newlist = [ abs(lst2[i]-lst2[i+1]) >= 0.1 and abs(lst2[i]-lst2[i-1]) >= 0.1 for i in range(1, len(lst)+1)] 

# result newlist
# [True, True, True, False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use numpy, in which case there's no need for explicit loops (Skycc's answer does the same, but is more concise):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5.1, 5.6, 6.0, 10.34, 10.37, 10.45, 12.5])

delta = np.diff(a) # forward difference
delta = np.insert(delta, 0, delta[0]) # duplicate the first delta at the beginning
delta = np.append(delta, delta[-1]) # duplicate last delta at the end

valid = np.abs(delta) >= 0.1 # boolean vector
```